# Recognizing subgraphs with networkx in Python

Tags: python-2.7, networkx

I have a 3x3 square lattice where each node is connected to its perpendicular neighbors. Since it is a repeating lattice, outer nodes on one side are connected to outer nodes on the other side. For example, in [this diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJMnq.png), the node '0, 0' is connected to '0, 2' and '2, 0' (as well as '0, 1' and '1, 0').

I would like to identify [horizontal subgraphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dITwe.png) (e.g. '0, 0', '1, 0', '2, 0') using NetworkX. Here is my code:

```
import networkx as nx
import networkx.algorithms.isomorphism as iso
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


wrap = True #If True, outer nodes are connected to nodes on opposite end
size = 3
pos = {}

big_graph = nx.Graph()    
#Create nodes
for i in xrange(size):
    for j in xrange(size):
        current_node = '{}, {}'.format(i, j)
        big_graph.add_node(current_node, i = i, j = j)
        pos[current_node] = np.array([i, j])

#Create edges
for i in xrange(size):
    for j in xrange(size):
        current_node = '{}, {}'.format(i, j)
        #Add edge to connect node above
        if i != 0:
            big_graph.add_edge(current_node, '{}, {}'.format(i-1, j), direction = 'hor')
        elif wrap:
            big_graph.add_edge(current_node, '{}, {}'.format(size-1, j), direction = 'hor')

        #Add edge to connect node below
        if i != (size-1):
            big_graph.add_edge(current_node, '{}, {}'.format(i+1, j), direction = 'hor')
        elif wrap:
            big_graph.add_edge(current_node, '{}, {}'.format(0, j), direction = 'hor')

        #Add edge to connect node above
        if j != 0:
            big_graph.add_edge(current_node, '{}, {}'.format(i, j-1), direction = 'vert')
        elif wrap:
            big_graph.add_edge(current_node, '{}, {}'.format(i, size-1), direction = 'vert')

        #Add edge to connect node below
        if j != (size-1):
            big_graph.add_edge(current_node, '{}, {}'.format(i, j+1), direction = 'vert')
        elif wrap:
            big_graph.add_edge(current_node, '{}, {}'.format(i, 0), direction = 'vert')

#Print Node information
print 'Nodes:'
print 'n    Node   i  j'
for i, node in enumerate(sorted(big_graph.nodes_iter())):
    print '{:2d}   {}   {}  {}'.format(i, node, nx.get_node_attributes(big_graph, 'i')[node], nx.get_node_attributes(big_graph, 'j')[node])
print '-'*10

#Print Edge information
print 'Edges:'
print 'n    Nodes                  Direction'
for i, edge in enumerate(sorted(big_graph.edges_iter())):
    print '{:2d}   {}       {}'.format(i, edge, nx.get_edge_attributes(big_graph, 'direction')[edge])
print '-'*10


#Subgraph to recognize
small_graph = nx.Graph()
small_graph.add_nodes_from(['A', 'B', 'C'])
small_graph.add_edge('A', 'B', direction = 'hor')
small_graph.add_edge('B', 'C', direction = 'hor')


#Print edge information
print 'Small graph edges'
for i, edge in enumerate(sorted(small_graph.edges_iter())):
    print '{} {}  {}'.format(i, edge, nx.get_edge_attributes(small_graph, 'direction')[edge])
    #print '{}'.format(edge, nx.get_edge_attributes(small_graph))
print '-'*10

#Find subgraphs
GM = iso.GraphMatcher(big_graph, small_graph, edge_match=iso.categorical_edge_match('direction', ''))
subgraph_list = []
print 'Subgraphs found'
for i, subgraph in enumerate(GM.subgraph_isomorphisms_iter()):
    print '{}\t{}'.format(i, subgraph)
    subgraph_list.append(subgraph)
print 'Number of subgraphs: {}'.format(len(subgraph_list))


#Draw the graph
pos=nx.spring_layout(big_graph, pos = pos)
nx.draw(big_graph, pos = pos, node_size = 700)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(big_graph, pos = pos)
plt.show()
```

When wrap is set to False, it gives the answer I would expect:

```
Subgraphs found
0   {'0, 0': 'A', '1, 0': 'B', '2, 0': 'C'}
1   {'0, 1': 'A', '1, 1': 'B', '2, 1': 'C'}
2   {'1, 2': 'B', '0, 2': 'A', '2, 2': 'C'}
3   {'1, 2': 'B', '0, 2': 'C', '2, 2': 'A'}
4   {'0, 0': 'C', '1, 0': 'B', '2, 0': 'A'}
5   {'0, 1': 'C', '1, 1': 'B', '2, 1': 'A'}
Number of subgraphs: 6
```

However, it can't find any subgraphs when wrap = True.

```
Subgraphs found
Number of subgraphs: 0
```

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: My interpretation is that it can't find subgraphs when you use `wrap=True` because the start and end node are missing because they are unspecified. Which is to say, when you wrap the lattice, it kind of behaves like a sphere, and as you walk on its surface, there's no physical start or endpoint. Does it make sense?

Comment: @FaCoffee That's really interesting. I change size to 4 while still looking for a horizontal subgraph of length 3 and it worked. That makes a lot of sense now! Thanks! I wish I could mark your suggestion as the answer.

Comment: I've just turned my comment into an answer, so please feel free to mark it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My interpretation is that it can't find subgraphs when you use `wrap=True` because the start and end node are missing - they are unspecified. Which is to say, when you wrap the lattice, it kind of behaves like a sphere, and as you walk on its surface, there's no physical start or endpoint.

My suggestion is to change `size`, as you said you did, or stick with `wrap=False` if possible.